# Why Netty 4 "proxy" example has to set channel "AUTO_READ" as false

Tags: java, netty

In Netty 4 ["proxy" example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy), the channel auto read option has been disabled:

```
serverBootStrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
    ...
    .childOption(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false)
```

If commented `childOption(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false)`, the proxy example will cannot work. And more detailed, in the method `channelRead` of the class `HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler`, the `outboundChannel` will always be inactive.

And I have researched Netty source code, found that "auto read" will affect  like that in methods `fireChannelActive` and `fireChannelReadComplete` of the class `DefaultChannelPipeline`

```
if (channel.config().isAutoRead()) {
    read();
}
```

But I still cannot figure out what the relationship between auto read and the proxy example. In my mind, when a data send to the inbound buffer, Netty should fire the channel read event.

So there are two questions:

- Why disable auto read is necessary for "proxy" example?
- Why enable auto read will make `outboundChannel` always inactive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have not set autoread to false you may get into trouble if one channel writes a lot of data before the other can consume it. As it's all asynchronous you may end up with buffers that have too much data and hit OOME.

Comment: May be if autoread is true will cause OOME. But why enable this option will make Netty proxy example cannot work completely?

Comment: the problem is that if you not set it to false you may start to read before you are connected to the remote peer.

Comment: Hi Maurer, So you mean auto read option is true will make the method `fireChannelActive` to invoke the channel read event before this channel is real active. Then because the read event happened too early, so the data will be miss. Is my understand right?

Comment: correct... This can happen when the establish of the connection takes too long.

Comment: but if i need an authentication before the reverse connection is setted up, how can do? such as, the client http request header or cookie must have something