# Blocking tcp packet receiving in Netty 4.x

Tags: proxy, netty

How can I block `netty` to send ACK responese to client in netty 4.x ?

I'm trying to control TCP packet receive speed in netty in order to forward these packet to another server .  Netty receive all client packets immediately ,but netty need more time send them out , so client think it finished after sending to netty .

So , I want to know how to block received packets when netty forwarding packets which are received before to another server .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to really understand your question. So I try to reformulate:

- I suppose that your Netty server is acting as a Proxy between clients and another server.
- I suppose that what you want to do is to send the ack back to the client only once you really send the forwarded packet to the final server (not necesseraly received by the final server, but at least send by Netty proxy).

If so, then you should use the future of the forwarded packet to respond back with the ack, such as (pseudo code):

```
channelOrCtxToFinalServer.writeAndFlush(packetToForward).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
  public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
    // Perform Ack write back
    ctxOfClientChannel.writeAndFlush(AckPacket);
  }
});
```

where:

- `channelOrCtxToFinalServer` is one of `ChannelHandlerContext` or `Channel` connected to your remote final server from your Netty proxy,
- and `ctxOfClientChannel` is the current `ChannelHandlerContext` from your Netty handler that receive the packet from the client in `public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctxOfClientChannel, Object packetToForward)` method.

---

**EDIT:**
For the big file transfer issue, you can have a look at the Proxy example [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy).

In particular, pay attention on the following:

- Using the same logic, pay attention on receiving data one by one from client:

  ```
  yourServerBootstrap..childOption(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
  // Allow to control one by one the speed of reception of client's packets
  ```
- In your frontend handler:

  ```
  public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
      if (outboundChannel.isActive()) {
          outboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
              @Override
              public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                  if (future.isSuccess()) {
                      // was able to flush out data, start to read the next chunk
                      ctx.channel().read();
                  } else {
                      future.channel().close();
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```
- And finally add, using the very same logic, the final ack to your client (ack depending of course on your protocol): (see [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler.java) and [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyBackendHandler.java))

  ```
  /**
   * Closes the specified channel after all queued write requests are flushed.
   */
  static void closeOnFlush(Channel ch) {
      if (ch.isActive()) {
          ch.writeAndFlush(AckPacket).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks Frederic ~ you got my point correctly .but your suggestion didn't solve my problem . forgive my bad english .  i have a big file need to be forwareded (more than 6000kb ) . First , client (the 3 party client) send it to netty in 1 second and the progress bar shown 100% on client . i think netty accepts all file and cache them in buffer.  And then , begin forwarding . at last ,send server response to clent . so , client will stay 100% for a long time for waitting response . I want client wait netty forward each packet rather than send all file at once .

Comment: Maybe I should ask first: what are your handlers and encoder/decoder? The reason of this question is: more than 6000kb is send through several packets, so you can of course manage the forward to the next server packet by packet too. But in addition, you can manage the "readable" attribute of your Netty server, such that once it get a packet, it will disable the read process of the incoming channel (client's one) until it finished the write to the final server, then reactivate the readability of the client's channel. Doing this way, you can manage the speed of packet reception.

Comment: I edit my answear to explain by the proxy example from Netty what I have in mind... Hoping it helps you...

Comment: I have tried to use ' SetAutoRead' already , and i can block netty send buffer to my handler . but i can't block client send packets to netty . maybe client sent them to netty's cache . 'Readable' attribute just blocks cache send buffer to handler . i think netty receives packets on the low-level layer automatic . A application layer protocol will send all data with  many packets at once , such as a HttpRequest , POP3 , they are  uncontrollable ? BTW , i have used many handlers for encode and decode buffers . need i send my code you ? very thanks :P

Comment: Auto_read prevent client to send anything to Netty server, since it blocks the read operation, therefore blocks the incoming message from the client. See other question on auto_read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273305/why-netty-4-proxy-example-has-to-set-channel-auto-read-as-false

Comment: I have resolved it . i tried to use sync way to set forward bootstrap (netty to destination server) . and serverbootstrap was blocked  ...:P , Thanks Frederic again ~~ . another question is i didn't see 'Auto_read' attribute . which object has this attribute  or how to use ?

Comment: See my "EDIT" beginning: `yourServerBootstrap..childOption(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false)` and the following which shows how to use it (in particular where `ctx.channel().read();` is used).