# Netty how to completely ignore TCP/UDP packets from unknown IPs

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to create a SOCKS proxy implementation using Netty and I need to drop packets from unknown hosts/IPs. It should behave like a firewall if the packet received from unknown host it should drop it and do not send any packets in responce.

```
    IpFilterRule[] rules = new IpFilterRule[2];
    rules[0] = new IpSubnetFilterRule("127.0.0.1", 8, IpFilterRuleType.ACCEPT); 
    rules[1] = new IpSubnetFilterRule("127.0.0.1", 0, IpFilterRuleType.REJECT);

    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
    bootstrap.group(boss, worker)
    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024)
    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 1000)
    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

            ch.pipeline().addFirst(ipFilter);

            ch.pipeline().addLast(new IdleStateHandler(3, 30, 0));
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new ProxyIdleHandler());
            // some socks channel pipeline initialization
        }
    });
```

Edit 1: After I've added IP filter to the channel pipeline I can still see SYN ACK responces and FIN ACK, RST ACK packets from my Netty proxy server 192.168.56.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would RuleBasedIpFilter.accept() be of any help?

```
 @Override
  protected boolean accept(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, InetSocketAddress remoteAddress) throws Exception {
    for (IpFilterRule rule : rules) {
      if (rule == null) {
        break;
      }

      if (rule.matches(remoteAddress)) {
        return rule.ruleType() == IpFilterRuleType.ACCEPT;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I would like to create my own implementation of it later but now I would like to know how to attach it to the bootstrap with my ChannelInitializer. And if I do it wouldn't netty send some TCP responce? I'm new to netty.

Comment: @zur13 You can configure the rules not to send TCP response. https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer

Comment: @zur13 Also, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961506/blocking-tcp-packet-receiving-in-netty-4-x

Comment: But for this rules , In any case  you will receive the package. So the sender can make DDOS attack at layer 7.  The best is doing that before receiving the package. Kernel side iptables ? or  java has this ability ?      CAN SOME ONE write an idea ? ?

Comment: You will need to do this on the kernel level (iptables)

Answer (score 0):

With Netty, you can only drop messages at application layer. You cannot drop packets at the network layer with Netty. The network stack of the operating system will ACK the TCP packet before pushing that packet to Netty.