# ChannelOption.AUTO_READ and GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler

Tags: netty

I noticed that GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler won't limit traffic if AUTO_READ is set to false. But from comments on this thread [Why Netty 4 "proxy" example has to set channel "AUTO_READ" as false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273305/why-netty-4-proxy-example-has-to-set-channel-auto-read-as-false) Norman mentions that AUTO_READ false is set to prevent OOME. I guess one could see why controlling networking could fill up the buffers and lead to OOME.

Is there a way around this situation or is just one tradeoff when we enable traffic shaping we have to deal with?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When auto_read is false, write limit is ok, read limit is not working well.
If you're developing a proxy server, you can set GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler to another outgoing of the proxy.
The code  like this:

```
GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler gtsh = <server’s gtsh>
another_ctx.pipeline().addFirst(gtsh)
```