# ByteBuf release scenarios

Tags: java, netty

Recently we upgrade from Netty 3.x to latest 4.x.  After the upgrade, we found in our production system the dreaded OOM specific to Netty ByteBuf.

We turned on leak detection using the system property but for some reason this doesn't seem to output anything in our logs and we still eventually get the OOM Netty Error.

To avoid OOM, we are using the following where we can to allow Netty to manage releasing of the message/ByteBuf:

SimpleChannelInboundHandler - releases the read message 
ByteToMessageDecoder - releases the ByteBuf

The remaining places I have a hunch could produce a problem if exceptions occur.

Scenario 1:
Reading an input stream and creating a ByteBuf for each read and then writing the ByteBuf to a Channel.  I could see where when writing to the channel its closed or has an exception, this ByteBuf is never read and is never released. If this occurs, must I release that ByteBuf?  I tried to release it during my testing but then I get an exception because it doesn't have any refs.  If it doesn't have any references then is it truly creating a memory leak?  I did read on another question that you need to read all of the bytes then release the ByteBuf.  Is this true?

Scenario 2:
I have a 2 established channels.  When I receive a message on 1 channel, we simply write it to another channel.  When no exceptions occur, then the other channel that we send the ByteBuf to will release the ByteBuf after consuming and sending the bytes.  However lets say writing it to the other channel fails with an exception because that channel is now closed or something.  Again this ByteBuf is never read because it failed to be written to the other channel.  If this occurs, must I release the ByteBuf?  Yet again do I need to consume it and then release it?

Comment: Leak detection only prints errors once the garbage collection and the finalizers have ran, depending on the amount of garbage you produce in the code, this can take a while. One of the things you can try is decreasing the pool size

Comment: I think you are facing this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273305/why-netty-4-proxy-example-has-to-set-channel-auto-read-as-false

Comment: Thank You for the comment and I will research that as a possibility to my issue, however I would like to know specifically in those situations if I need to consume the ByteBuf then release it.  I tried to release it in those scenarios but I get a reference error.  So I believe I need to consume the bytes then release the byte buffer if there is an exception passing it along or unable to pass the ByteBuf along?

Comment: The post about back pressure with NIO was exactly that!  The proxy example however is lacking in performance so instead of controlling the read after each proxy write, we are using the write-ability event to throttle the reads